# How to connect to mysql container?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running official mysql docker image on Linux:

```
docker run --name somemysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
```

How do I connect to the database from outside of the container?

Comment: Take a read: https://docs.docker.com/network/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to specify the port to container with something like `-p 3306:3306`, which means you redirect your host `3306` port to the `3306` container port and then you just need connect by `exec` to the container like:

`$ docker exec -it somemysql bash` and you can access it easily, otherwise if you want to connect via mysql client use:

`$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`

It's important to specify the localhost IP. If you don't, you wont be able to connect. The port 3306 can't be in use when you assign it.

Comment: I can't exec. I must be able to connect from another physical machine.

Comment: You need to indicate the ip addr in the -h param to connect it. Like 
mysql -h 177.232.81.138 -u root -p

Answer (score 1):

First you have to open the Ports via -p expose is Not enough, since it is used in a network for multiple container to find each other without connection to the outside. Then you can connect to your container with exec and then via SSL

Comment: Now you can use the terminal as i described above or you use a Database Viewer as DBeaver and Connect to Port 3306